# Getting current location on Glass (latitude,longitude)

Tags: gps, google-glass, google-gdk

i'm trying to get current glass location with latitude and longitude, but I saw that Glass does not have a built-in GPS, but it will use the android smartphone connected with `MyGlass` to get the GPS, but I got nothing, so I always have a null lat/longitude

I've read that I need to use some Criteria or something??

The app it this one: **http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/** ,with my phone is ok got my latitude and longitude  but when I'm executing it on glass (a part of the code,not the whole) I got 0.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'll have to use a Criteria to configure the LocationProvider.
For example, you could use this snippet:

```
LocationManager locationManager; // initialized elsewhere

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(criteria, true /* enabledOnly */);

for (String provider : providers) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, listener);
}
```

But be careful not to use `LocationManager.getBestProvider()` method or the constants `GPS_PROVIDER` or `NETWORK_PROVIDER` to listen for location updates because Google Glass uses a different set of LocationProvider than regulare Android devices.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/location-sensors)

Comment: Hi, finally got it working, got some problems with th enetwork actually, thanks for you help!

Comment: The problem is back, even with criteria... Now that's always 0.0 in latitude/longitude when launching the app on google glasses, but on my phone it's working. any ideas??

Comment: I've noticed a thing, I'm able to get gps coordinates (latitude,longitude) only by share my phone's connection by hotspot, even though MyGlass shares the internet data by bluetooth... I also can't get values with GPS provider... By network provider I can't get the speed and the bearing